# add group of data depend on their position

Tags: r

This is my data

```
test2
   start_first length start_second length_second row_dna   evalue end_first
1       145317     30       153190            30       2 3.33e+08    145347
2       145315     31       153188            31       6 1.23e+08    145346
3       145314     30       153186            32      10 4.47e+07    145344
4       145312     31       153184            33      14 1.60e+07    145343
5       145310     31       153183            32      18 4.47e+07    145341
6       145317     31       262038            33      22 1.60e+07    145348
8       145316     31       262036            34      30 5.67e+06    145347
10      145314     31       262034            37      38 2.36e+05    145345
11      153186     32       178732            33      42 1.60e+07    153218
12      145317     35       178735            30      46 1.99e+06    145352
13      178737     33       245830            38      50 7.99e+04    178770
14      178736     33       245829            37      54 2.36e+05    178769
15      178733     32       245828            34      58 5.67e+06    178765
16      145317     30       178737            32      62 4.47e+07    145347
17      145316     30       178736            32      66 4.47e+07    145346
18      145318     32       221384            33      70 1.60e+07    145350
19      145317     31       221383            32      74 4.47e+07    145348
20      145315     31       221383            30      78 1.23e+08    145346
```

I want to assign a group in each row depend on start_first and start_second columns

This is my expect output

```
test2
   start_first length start_second length_second row_dna   evalue end_first group
1       145317     30       153190            30       2 3.33e+08    145347 1
2       145315     31       153188            31       6 1.23e+08    145346 1
3       145314     30       153186            32      10 4.47e+07    145344 1
4       145312     31       153184            33      14 1.60e+07    145343 1
5       145310     31       153183            32      18 4.47e+07    145341 1
6       145317     31       262038            33      22 1.60e+07    145348 2
8       145316     31       262036            34      30 5.67e+06    145347 2
10      145314     31       262034            37      38 2.36e+05    145345 2
11      153186     32       178732            33      42 1.60e+07    153218 3
12      145317     35       178735            30      46 1.99e+06    145352 3
13      178737     33       245830            38      50 7.99e+04    178770 4
14      178736     33       245829            37      54 2.36e+05    178769 4
15      178733     32       245828            34      58 5.67e+06    178765 4
16      145317     30       178737            32      62 4.47e+07    145347 5
17      145316     30       178736            32      66 4.47e+07    145346 5
18      145318     32       221384            33      70 1.60e+07    145350 6
19      145317     31       221383            32      74 4.47e+07    145348 6
20      145315     31       221383            30      78 1.23e+08    145346 6
```

The criteria that i used to group my data is depend on the position only. First just look at the start first and the start second column so the row one to the row six have very similar position so these all row are group together

The row in the same group should have a very close position to each other  (should not more than 10 position)

Is there a way to solve this question. Thank you for any answer.

Comment: hm, how to group the following 11 items: `153001 .. 153011` ? Which one should be in the other group `153001` or `153011`? The description of your algorithm is not clear to me. Please edit your question.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your point. Could you give me more explanation because I think my data did not  have the number that your mention

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the following could cover - in principle - what you are looking for. Some further tweaking might be needed, however.

```
distMatrix = as.matrix(dist(cbind(data$start_second, data$start_second))) # Get  distances between rows
hist(distMatrix, breaks = 1000)

threshold = 500 # Set a threshold for grouping. Change as desired 
distMatrix.bool = distMatrix < threshold


assigned.i = c() # Keep track of assigned rows, to avoid redundancy
data$group2 = -1 # Initialzie a new column 

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) { # Loop over the rows

  if(i %in% assigned.i) # move to the next loop if already assigned 
    next

  sameGroup = which(distMatrix.bool[i,])
  data$group2[sameGroup] = i

  assigned.i = c(assigned.i, sameGroup)
}



assigned.i = c() # Keep track of assigned rows, to avoid redundancy
data$group3 = -1 # Initialzie a new column 

j = 1 # Group counter 

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) { # Loop over the rows

  if(i %in% assigned.i) # move to the next loop if already assigned 
    next

  sameGroup = which(distMatrix.bool[i,])
  data$group3[sameGroup] = j
  j = j + 1

  assigned.i = c(assigned.i, sameGroup)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That exactly that I want but could you explain why I need to do a distance matrix and group3

Comment: @Vayami You're welcome :-) . We need the distance matrix since the only way we can group your data, according to your description, is similarity. That is why we took a distance threshold also. Group2 assigns the row index we are comparing to the group. So we don't have the groups in numerical sequence (ie: 1,2 , ... number of groups). Group3 does that. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation. it make me more clear about that point.